# Angular frequency in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

When using `siunitx`, is there an intuitive way to type angular frequencies with the prefix `2\pi \times`? The provided example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{2\pi x 100}{\mega\hertz}
\end{document}
```

yields 
[image]

So is there a neat way to supress the first unit?

Comment: You can use the `[parse-numbers=false]` to leave the number intact but if you have 2pi factor I think you are looking for `rad/s` no?

Comment: @percusse No, then the ` x ` is not parsed as a `\times` command. 
The `2\pi` is just a helpful way to avoid confusion whether the angular or the bare frequency is used, if you want to avoid to specify this in each instance used.

Comment: But you are making things difficult for siunitx since you both want parsing but also don't want the great functionality when you write `3m x 5m`. So `\times` is needed there if you don't want the parsing. Also I wouldn't call it a helpful way. We are constantly correcting this behavior in the papers. Units are not ambiguous. `100 Mrad/s` is precisely what you wrote. `100 MHz` is the bare number. Note that I didn't write any `2pi` factor in any of them.

Comment: @percusse you are totally right that the correct SI unit is `\radian\per\second`, and I think I would certainly use it to write an angular frequency describing a real rotation. But consider a harmonic oscillator, or LC circuit if you want, the rad/s unit is confusing. Actually, I can not remember having seen it anywhere in usage in physics, at least not within my community.

Comment: I see. In the control field or electrical engineering in general it's kind of the standard unit. I didn't think of physics though.

Comment: I have to agree, in physics, writing `omega = 2pi x f` is the common way of writing these two things, because it includes both, frequency and angular freqency, at once and because this way there's no chance to confuse them.

Comment: @FooBar That's only correct if you also modify the definition of the Fourier transform. omega = `2pi x f` can be `Hz.` or `rad/s` so it's not that straightforward to distinguish. If f = 100 Hz, then `2pi x f` is `rad/s`. Much to my annoyance, all MATLAB plots are `rad/s` as the default setting for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is the following: I can choose the default behaviour when calling the package, and control then for each call of `\SI` the output where it deviates from the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[product-units=repeat]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[product-units=single]{2\pi x 100}{\mega\hertz}

\SI{2 x 2}{\meter}
\end{document}
```

gives the desired output:

[image]

**EDIT**

The usage as such is preferred to plain writing as we have access to all the features of the `siunitx` package, such as preventing line breaks etc.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
This is text which should induce a line break
\SI[product-units=single]{2\pi x 100}{\mega\hertz}

This is text which should induce a line break
$2 \times \SI{100}{\mega\hertz}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really see why this is better than `$2\pi \times \SI{100}{\mega\hertz}$` or a new command, which both would even be shorter and more clear and without the need of repeated command options.

Comment: I've added an example where I compared the solutions for line breaking.

Comment: Curly brackets in math avoid line breaking: `${2\pi \times \SI{1}{\hertz}}$` will never linebreak.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that one. But than, you have to add it manually for every use. I thought it is one of the purposes of the package to write all quantities with `\num` and `\SI` just to have better control of the behaviour.

Comment: You only have to add it when it actually breaks, which will happen very rarely (proof-reading is a must with LaTeX in all cases). Or add it to the self-defined command, then it will always be there. Speaking semantically as a physicist myself, I don't think that `2pi` belongs to the physical quantity. It's only a mathematical factor, it's neither the unit nor the value. Taking something "times 2pi" is a mathematical operation.

Comment: Well, I guess we are now starting arguing about matters of taste. Anyway, I think it is good style to write commands in such a way that you automatically get the intended line breaking regardless what text is before them. So I usually write things like `~\ref` and `~\cite` instead of ` \ref` and ` \cite`, so I don't need to worry for this things during proof reading and I can focus on spotting real errors.

Comment: I agree. :) In the end you have to decide for yourself. But since this website is read by many people looking for help we should provide them all possible information to help them decide for themself. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
${2\pi \times \SI{100}{\mega\hertz}}$
```

Or this:

```
\newcommand*{\angfreq} [2] {2\pi \times \SI{#1}{#2\hertz}}
\angfreq{5}{\mega} % gives "2pi x 5 Mhz"
\angfreq{8}{\kilo} % gives "2pi x 8 khz"
```

With both ways you avoid situations where `product-units=single` as a global option would give wrong results on other values and you avoid repeating this option on every single angular frequency when not using it as a global option.

Comment: Ok, this solves the problem for the `\mega\hertz`. But then I need to define another one for `\kilo\hertz`, `\giga\hertz` etc.

Comment: I changed the code a bit. Just pass two arguments to `\angfreq`, the first is the number, the second is the frequency.

Comment: I think this is quite the workaround I've wanted. Still I feel strange having a common framework for all other units, and needing a special command for angular frequencies

Comment: But `2pi x` is no unit, so I think it's just natural that you need something special for this. The "unit way" for angular frequencies would be `rad/s` (talking sloppy: `rad` basically means `x 2pi`).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Good idea, I changed it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the following all you need or am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI[product-units = single]{2\pi x 100}{\MHz}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: But he's also using other values and units, which could be wrong this way, if the option is set globally. And always typing `[product-units=single]` on every single angular frequency locally can also be rather annoying if you have many of them.

Comment: I see; good point.

Comment: But I can use the option also for each `\SI` where I need it, or choose globally one option for the case used the most, and switch for the others. That's perfect, thanks.